# Android-Send data from an application to a lamp Server

Tags: android, database, store, send, lamp

I want to send data from my android application to a lamp server and store this data on a database. I don't have experience in that because it's my first time that i set up a lamp server and create a database which will communicate with an android application. To tell you shortly i made an android app that takes a photo and makes ocr. I want to take the resullt which is for example a product name and a price, and send it to server in order to store it in the database. I searched the web but i got little confused because i saw a lot of different methods in order to do this. So, what i want to ask you is that which is the best way to do this and how i'm going to do it?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sending data from an android App is no different from any other client that you can think of, call it WebApp, Java App or any other application capable of doing HTTP Request, as long as you have the proper server side code (PHP), to catch the request parameters sent from HTTP Request made by the client, connecting to Database and populating the values, of course is very important to take on count one of the Authentication mechanisms available, so just people that you actually care can hit the server and populate the Database.

Here is an example how to do Http request using "GET" method in Android: http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/01/httpclient-and-httpget.html, if "POST" method is what you need this example is perfect: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

In order to catch those values there's tons of examples in PHP to do that...

Hope these examples help and Good luck...

Regards!